# How to Structure data for Apriori Algorithm?

Tags: r, apriori, arules

I want to see if users who tweet about one thing also tweet about something else. I've used the TwittR package in R studio to download tweets containing keywords and then downloaded the timelines of those users in python. My data is structured as follows.

user_name,id,created_at,text

exampleuser,814495243068313603,2016-12-29 15:36:13, 'MT @nixon1788: Obama and the Left are disgusting anti Semitic pukes! #WithdrawUNFunding'

Is it possible to use the apriori algorithm to generate association rules? Does anyone know how to structure this data in order to use it or if it is even possible with the data I have?

Comment: see the [arule r package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/index.html)

Comment: What kind of associations are you looking to determine here? Associations between hashtags. Or associations between the name Obama and negative tweets. Either way, I think @ImranAli suggestion would go a long way.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I want to use keywords (so if someone tweets using the word obama will they also tweet using the word "clinton" for example)  my problem is I don't know how to coerce my data into transactional data to use with this package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example as a starter:

```
txt <- c("Trump builds a wall", "Trump goes wall", "Obama buys drones", "Drones by Obama")
library(quanteda)
library(arules)
dfm <- dfm(txt)
trans <- as(as.matrix(dfm), "transactions")
rules <- apriori(
  data = trans, 
  parameter = list(minlen = 2L, maxlen=2, conf = 1), 
  appearance = list(lhs = c("obama", "trump"), default="rhs")
)
inspect(rules)
#   lhs        rhs      support confidence lift
# 1 {obama} => {drones} 0.5     1          2   
# 2 {trump} => {wall}   0.5     1          2
```

Comment: Hi, this example works perfectly thanks! Just wondering, i'm getting this error when trying to coerce my own large dataset into a dfm: "Error in validObject(r) : 
  invalid class “dgTMatrix” object: length(Dimnames[1]) differs from Dim[1] which is 8" Any idea how to get rid of it?

Comment: similar problem has been reported on [github repo of the quanteda package](https://github.com/kbenoit/quanteda/issues/168). As suggested on the page try to update quanteda from github using [devtools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/index.html)